# What is a word that means "unwilling to learn"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I train people in software and sometimes the students are resistant or unwilling to learn. I would like to know if there is a word to describe these people.

Comment: A sample sentence please.

Comment: "Dense" is the old high school term for this.

Answer (score 0):

My personal favourite would be willfully ignorant - not only do they not know, they also refuse to learn!

Answer (score -2):

Recalcitrant is a good one I think.